# show reply button not working fine for comments

Tags: python, django, show-hide

show Reply button should be specific for different comments . When I press show reply button it opens different replies which dosen't belong to that comment.

1. views.py

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect,reverse
> from fitness.models import Post, BlogComment
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> from fitness.templatetags import extras
>
> # Create your views here.
> def fitness(request):
>     everypost=Post.objects.all()
>     context={"everypost":everypost}
>     return render(request, "fitness/fit.html", context)
>
>
> def blogfit(request, slug):
>     post=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
>     comments= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post, parent=None)
>     replies= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post).exclude(parent=None)
>     replyDict={}
>     for reply in replies:
>         if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
>             replyDict[reply.parent.sno]=[reply]
>         else:
>             replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
>
>     context={"post":post, 'comments': comments, 'user': request.user, 'replyDict': replyDict}
>     return render(request, "fitness/blogfit.html", context)
>
> def postComment(request):
>     if request.method == "POST":
>         comment=request.POST.get('comment')
>         user=request.user
>         postSno =request.POST.get('postSno')
>         post= Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)
>         parentSno= request.POST.get('parentSno')
>         if parentSno=="":
>             comment=BlogComment(comment= comment, user=user, post=post)
>             comment.save()
>
>         else:
>             parent= BlogComment.objects.get(sno=parentSno)
>             comment=BlogComment(comment= comment, user=user, post=post , parent=parent)
>             comment.save()
>     return HttpResponse(reverse('fitness:fitness'))
> ```

2. Models.py

> ```
> from django.db import models
> from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> from django.utils.timezone import now
> # Create your models here.
>
> class Post(models.Model):
>     sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
>     title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     author=models.CharField(max_length=14)
>     slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
>     timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
>     content=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.title + " by " + self.author
> class BlogComment(models.Model):
>     sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
>     comment=models.TextField()
>     user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>     parent=models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )
>     timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now)
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.comment[0:13] + "..." + "by" + " " + self.user.username
> ```

3. Html page

   ```
              <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
               <p class="blog-post-meta">{{post.timeStamp}} by <a href="#">{{post.author}}</a></p>


          <p>{{post.content|safe}}</p>

          <hr>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <form action="{% url 'fitness:postComment' %}" method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Post Comment </label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Enter comment here">
           </div>
           <input type="hidden" name="postSno" value="{{post.sno}}">
           <input type="hidden" name="parentSno" value="">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </form>
       {% else %}
       Please login to post a comment
       {% endif %}
   </div>
   {% for comment in comments %}
   <div class="row my-3">
       <div class="col-md-1  ">
           <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block w-100 border border-dark p-2" src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt="user">

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11 ">
         <h6 class="comment-name by-author"> {{comment.user.username}} </h6> <span class="badge badge-secondary "></span>
      <b> {{comment.comment}} </b> <span class="badge badge-secondary "></span><br>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#replyBox{{comment.sno}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="replyBox{{comment.sno}}">
          Reply
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" onClick="myFunction()" id= "show-hide" >
          Show Replies
      </button>


           <div class="reply mx-0" >


               <div class="collapse" id="replyBox{{comment.sno}}">
                   <div class="card card-body my-2" >
                       <form action="{% url 'fitness:postComment' %}" method="post">
                           {% csrf_token %}
                           <div class="form-group" >
                               <label for="comment">Post a reply </label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Enter comment here">
                               <input type="hidden" name="parentSno" value="{{comment.sno}}">
                           </div>
                           <input type="hidden" name="postSno" value="{{post.sno}}">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                       </form>
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div class="replies bg-danger my-2" id = "replies" >
               {% for reply in replyDict|get_val:comment.sno %}
               <div class="replies">{{reply}}</div>
               <br>
               {% endfor %}
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}

   <!-- Contenedor Principal -->

   <script>
      function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById("replies");
        if(x.style.display === "none"){
          x.style.display = "block";

        }
        else{
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
   </script>
   ```

I think it is a logical error. Can someone help me to find out this error? While everything is working fine but my reply button not working fine.

Comment: replies= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post)..here is the problem..you are getting all replies of post..not by comment

Answer (score 0):

Change in `models.py`. update `parent` in `BlogComment` (add `related_name`)

```
parent=models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='replies' )
```

Change in `views.py` where you are getting `comments`

```
comments= BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post, parent=None).prefetch_related('replies')
```

You don't need separate query for replies.

In `html` (Only for replies. Please change as per your requirement)

```
{% for comment in comments %}
      {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        {{ reply.comment }}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will work. Remember `related_name=replies`

(Sorry for unclear answer. It's closing time in office and I am leaving. Good luck)